# Storing SelectedItem from WPF Treeview with composite collection items

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a WPF Treeview in my application. In this, I am showing folders and files. As these are different items, I am using the Composite Collection approach for binding the items to the treeview as suggested in [this link](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/wpf-treeview-data-binding-of-heterogeneous-types-of-data-datatemplate-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate/).

Now, I need to store the SelectedItem from WPF Treeview. For this, I want to define a property in ViewModel. But, the problem is that if define the property with FolderItem type, then this property is not hit when I select a File in the Treeview and vice-versa.

I need a way to store the selecteditem irrespective of whether it is folder or file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
kvk938

Answer (score 0):

You could either change the type of the property to `object` or a type that both your `FolderItem` class and your `File` inherits from (or implement if it is an interface type):

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class FolderItem : IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File : IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public IItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
```